# Elisp: how to find list duplicates

Tags: list, duplicates, lisp, elisp

I am using this to find list duplicates:

```
(defun have-dups (x)
  (let ((dups (copy-tree x)))
    (if (eq (length (delete-dups dups)) (length x))
    nil
      t)))

(have-dups (list 1 2 3 3)) ;=> t
(have-dups (list 1 2 3))   ;=> nil
```

Considering the overhead of `copy-tree` and `delete-dups`, probably there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a hash table, as soon as you find an element which already exists in the hash table, you know you have duplicates:

```
(defun has-dup (list)
  (block nil
    (let ((hash (make-hash-table :test 'eql)))
      (map ()
           (lambda (item)
             (if (gethash item hash)
                 (return t)
               (setf (gethash item hash) t)))
           list))))
```

Comment: Why have you used `(block nil (...))` wrapper, is it to be able to just call `return` instead of `return-from has-dup`? Also why have you included `nil` in the last line - the code seems to work without it as well? Sorry I'm just new to lisp.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev In elisp `defun` doesn't establish a block itself. The `nil` at the end doesn't seem necessary (since `(map () ...)` will always return `nil` anyway), but I assume it's there for readability.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev As jkiiski said. You can remove the last `nil` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version of your answer, which uses `remove-duplicates` instead of `delete-dups`, to avoid the destructive properties of the latter:

```
(defun has-dups-p (LIST) ""
       (let ((unique1 (remove-duplicates LIST :test #'equal)))
     (if (eq LIST unique1)
         nil
       t)))
(has-dups '(1 2 3 2 1)) ; t
(has-dups '("a" "b" "c")) ; nil
```

I find this reasonably easy to read and `eq` should be reasonably efficient as it goes straight to `C`, particularly where a duplicate occurs early in the list. Both `remove-duplicates` and `delete-dups` are passed to `cl--delete-duplicates` which is rather involved...

A longer solution follows, which returns the elements of `LIST` which have duplicates and the *position* of each *duplicated* element in `LIST` (remembering that `seq`s are zero-indexed in elisp). Note that this currently only applies where the elements of `LIST` are `string`s, although I'm sure it could be extended further to more general cases:

```
(defun list-duplicates (LIST) "
Returns `nil' when LIST has no duplicates.
Otherise, returns a `list' of `cons's.
In each list element:
- the `car' is the element of LIST which has duplicates.
- the `cdr' is a list of the positions where the duplicates are found."
   (interactive)
   ;; res1 = result
   ;; unique1 = LIST with duplicates removed
   (let ((unique1 (remove-duplicates LIST :test #'string-equal))
     (res1 '()))
     (if (eq LIST unique1)
     nil
       (progn
     (dolist (x unique1)
       ;; i = incrementor
       ;; pos1 = list of postions of duplicates
       (let (y (i 0) (pos1 '()))
         (while (member x LIST)
           (set 'y (seq-position LIST x))
           (when (> i 0)
         (push y pos1))
           (set 'i (+ 1 i))
           (set 'LIST
            (substitute (concat x "1") x LIST :test #'string-equal :count 1)))
         (push (cons x (nreverse pos1)) res1)))
     (nreverse res1)))))
```

e.g.

```
(list-duplicates '("a" "b" "c")) ; nil
(list-duplicates '("a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "c" "c")) ; (("a" 3) ("b" 2 4) ("c" 6))
```